# Separation of bits of ip address which is given in decimal format with dot separated after converting the address into binary numbers in java?

Tags: java, java-7

I have to convert 32 bit IP address given in decimal format with dot separated like "172.168.100.23"into string of 32 bit consecutive binary numbers like "10101100101010000110010000010111". Then I have to separate 7 MSB's i.e 1010110 and 25 bits i.e
0101010000110010000010111. What could I do? Is there any built in function that help me to solve my problem?

I am taking input into string

```
System.out.println("Enter an IP address");
String ip=input.next();
```

then converting it into substring

```
String delimiter="\\.";
String[] array=ip.split(delimiter);
String s4=array[0];
String s3=array[1];
String s2=array[2];
String s1=array[3];
```

then I convert each string into integer

```
int num4=Integer.parseInt(s4);
int num3=Integer.parseInt(s3);
int num2=Integer.parseInt(s2);
int num1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
```

After this i have to convert each number into to its binary and fill msb's with 0's if number's binary is less then 8 bit like (10111) it could be (00010111) to complete 32 bit.
After that i have to combine all separate bits of each number, and finally I have to separate 7 MSB's from other 25 bits.
Please help me to complete this problem

Comment: Have already answered this in you previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200861/how-can-character-be-added-at-the-end-of-string-in-java Can you say how this question is different.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use InetAddress

```
String ipAddress = "192.168.16.142";
InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress); 

for (Byte b : i.getAddress()) {
        Integer.toBinaryString(b); // Get your binary string 1110011101010110
}
```